# Part ArrayList<String > to 3 strings sublist ArrayList<String >

Tags: java, arraylist

I have unknown size of my ArrayList also it is always different size but it is cubic. Is there any way to part it to 3 strings subLists?

**Code:**

```
int number = mainList.size()/3;
for(int i= 1 ; i < mainList.size()/3; i++){
    int index = i*3 ;           
    List<RootCreator> sublist =  mainList.subList(0, index);
    mainSublist.addAll(sublist);
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This is trivial with methods such as [ArrayList#subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) + a for loop. Have you actually tried? If so, come back with a *specific* problem you are having.

Comment: `3^n` isn't cubic, it's exponential!

Comment: @Quirliom: I have tried the code above but I am getting just one subList in the mainSubList?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about 3^n part but in general assuming you have inputStrList list, now break it into 3 parts.

```
ArrayList<String> subList1 = new ArrayList<String>(inputStrList.subList(0, start));
ArrayList<String> subList2= new ArrayList<String>(inputStrList.subList(start+1, middle));
ArrayList<String> subList3= new ArrayList<String>(inputStrList.subList(middle+1, end));
```

Comment: I think this is not the answer that the OP mentioned.